# How to move saved html files with special name in a folder from console

Tags: html, windows, firefox, drag-and-drop

I was wondering if anyone knew how to move files with a special name associated with them in a folder without breaking its association or just moving the html file alone?

For instance, When you save a web page and it saves the current DOM document to a html file but leaves a **webpage_files** folder with supporting CSS, pictures, javascript, so on. The webpage_files moves with the file webpage.html if you drag and drop it in a folder to another.

**What I would really like to know is how to keep it and move it using a script** or restore it after it has been zipped. The move command does not have the same effect as when you drag and drop.

Comment: Good point! I did not check to see specifically if it had a junction point. Just assumed it had one based on behavior. Do you know what I am getting at when I ask how to move those connected files at the same time?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776887(VS.85).aspx#connected

Comment: I wouldn't try to emulate this behavior using a batch script, especially considering the name can be localized. Use a scripting language that lets you call `SHFileOperation`, such as Python w/ PyWin32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move both files at once I came up with this.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set X=5
set B=0
set FOLDER_PATH=.
pushd %FOLDER_PATH%
#REM If file not equal script.bat
for %%f in (*.html) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
    set "filename2=%%f"
    echo new %%~nf
    REM Move html file first
    move filename2 html
    REM Remove last X characters and move corresponding foldername
    move "!filename2:~%B%,-%X%!_files" html
)
popd
```